# Convert Image into ByteArray

Tags: c#, image, exception, arrays, gdi+

I know there already are plenty of post about this, but every solution I have tried so far failed. What I want is to get a `Byte[]` from an `Image` object.

What I have tried so far:

- `using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()){/*...*/}` **(GDI+ Exception)**
- Working on a copy of the `image` **(ArgumentNullException (Encoder))**
- Follow the [solution from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814675) **(ArgumentNullException (Encoder))**
- Use an `ImageConverter` **(GDI+ Exception)**

What I expect to have:

```
public static Byte[] BytesFromImage(Image img) {
Byte[] imgFile;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat);
imgfile = ms.ToArray();
return imgFile;
}
```

Everytime I get an error, it comes from `img.save(ms, img.RawFormat);`.

Maybe it is just me, but all of the solution that I've followed on StackOverflow gave me the same results: a GDI+ Error with such a great explanation.

Comment: Perhaps you should try `ImageFormat.MemoryBmp`.

Comment: Already tried this as well, it throws a ArgumentNullException for the Converter param

Answer (score 0):

Replace `img.RawFormat` with `ImageFormat.Bmp`

Example:

```
   class Program
    {

        public static byte[] BytesFromImage(Image img)
        {
            Byte[] imgFile;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            imgFile = ms.ToArray();
            return imgFile;
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Image image = new Bitmap(100, 100))
            {
                byte[] imgArr = BytesFromImage(image);

                Console.WriteLine("Image size is: {0}", imgArr.Length);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This should work for you. Just try a compatible ImageFormat type.